# Android Send sms when app not running in background

Tags: java, android, node.js, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there any way to send sms using `SmsManager` without open the App.
I am using `FirebaseMessagingService` and i got `remoteMessage` from `onMessageReceived` method its Contains Mobile No and Message.
Then i am sending SMS using using `SmsManager`. and also i declared `permission.SEND_SMS/RECEIVE_SMS` in manifest file.

This is My Code:

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage){

    String mobile = remoteMessage.getData().get("mobileno");
    String message = remoteMessage.getData().get("message");

    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(mobile, null, message, null, null);
}
```

Its Working on when App is Running. but not working on when app is not running in background.
**Is there any way to SEND sms when App is not running.??**
Please help me.. Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got answer from firebase console. i did some mistake in Nodejs Server code after corrected that code its working fine...

[image]